# Ember set belongsTo associantion works only first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

This code should provide the user a screen to update your portfolio's template.

In this screen, the server always returns 5 templates and the portfolio already has one template associated.

**models**

```
App.Portfolio = DS.Model.extend
  color: DS.attr 'string'
  template: DS.belongsTo 'template'


App.Template = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr 'string'
  portfolios: DS.hasMany('template')
```

**route**

```
App.PortfolioRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    this._super(controller,model);
    # load all templates for portfolio screen
    controller.set 'templates', this.store.find 'template'
```

**controller**

```
PortfoliosApplication.PortfolioController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  selectedTemplate: null

  testTemplateSelection: (->
    @set 'model.template', @get('selectedTemplate')
    console.log @get 'selectedTemplate'
    console.log @get 'model.template'
    console.log '--------'
  ).observes 'selectedTemplate'

  actions:
    changeTemplate: (template) ->
      @set 'selectedTemplate', template
```

**portfolio.hbs**

```
{{#each tmpl in templates}}
  <button {{action 'changeTemplate' tmpl}}> {{ tmpl.title }} </button>
{{/each}}

<h3>Template {{ template.title }}</h3>
```

This code works fine while user select an new template for the current portfolio. Example:

- Open portfolio with template 1
- Change to template 2
- save

But this does not works if select a template previously selected. Example:

- Open portfolio with template 1
- Change to template 2
- Change again to template 1 **Doesn't works**

At step three of last example, the screen doesn't get updated and the console logs:

```
selectedTemplate.id => 1
model.teplate.id => 2
--------
```

ie, the `@set 'model.template', @get('selectedTemplate')` doesn't updated the `template` property of `portfolio`.

I'm stuck in this bug. Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in Ember Data that has been fixed in master

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2360

See my JSBin to reproduce the problem

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/haweci/2/edit

You can comment/uncomment the version of Ember Data and reproduce that issue.

Also I had to fix your code to make it work:

- I'm using `RSVP.hash` to load the `templates` and `portfolio` in the `model` hook. You should not to any call to the `store.find` in `setupController`
- I load the `portfolio` in the `PortfolioController` and the `templates` in the `TemplatesController`.
- In order to use `templates` in your `portfolio` template, I create a dependency between `PortfolioController` and `TemplatesController` using `needs`
- No need to use an observer to set the template on the model, you can do that directly in the action handler.

Answer (score 0):

App.Template [needs](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_one-to-one) to belong to a App.Portfolo:

```
App.Portfolio = DS.Model.extend({
  color: DS.attr('string'),
  template: DS.belongsTo('template')
});

App.Template = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  portfolio: DS.belongsTo('portfolio'),
  portfolios: DS.hasMany('template')  
});
```

See [here](http://jsbin.com/lutuyigejoto/1/#/portfolio) for a fixed version of Cyril Fluck's jsbin

Comment: I'll try. But what is the reason to add `portolio` association to `template`? This is an EmberData bug?

Comment: @Rodrigo Have a read of the Ember documentation: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_one-to-one

Comment: Yes @Corvusoft, but `template` don't `belongsTo('portfolio')` . It only `hasMany('portfolio')`! Why should I declare this nonexistent association?